# Flask, Python: Trouble getting data from drop down menu to display on return render template

Tags: python, flask

I'm having trouble getting the values/results from the drop down menu to display on my results page. The value in the input box for name displays fine but when I try to display the values from the drop down menu, it errors out. Let me know if you have a solution. Thank you!

python, flask:

```
from flask import Flask , render_template, redirect, request
app = Flask(__name__)  

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/results', methods= ['GET','POST'])
def next():
    name = request.form['Name']
    city = request.form.get['city1','city2','city3']
    print(name, city)

    return render_template('results.html', name=name, city = city)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form action='/results' method = 'post'>
        <p>
            <label for="Name"> Your Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name">
            <input type='submit' value='submit'>
        </p>
        <p>
            <select name = city >
                <option value="SanJose" name = "city1">San Jose</option>
                <option value="Seattle" name = "city2">Seattle</option>
                <option value="LA" name = "city3">LA</option>
            </select>
        </p>
```

Comment: Your form is using a select field. The selected value can be accessed using the value for the name attribute of the select field. `city = request.form['city']`. `option` HTMLElement [doesn't have a name attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to get input from a select drop-down, just fetch the name of the overarching select which is "city" instead of all the possible options.

```
city = request.form['city']
```